# How to convert Sketch format file into vector file for Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, sketch-app, file-format, file-conversion

I'm trying to open a Sketch format file in Illustrator but Illustrator doesn't support it... How can I convert it to a vector format that Illustrator supports?

I only have Windows so cannot install Sketch to export another format.

Comment: Just like Paul Tunak, I had the same issue with convertio.co. Got octet stream errors on all sketch files I tried. I already had an account on Figma, so I tried it. Figma would let me go to each layer and export as SVG, or even PDF. Not sure if any of those formats will retain Layers. Tried more from Cai's post. Lunacy was a nice one (Windows), exporting to SVG as well I also tried Gravit Designer (Ubuntu). Its a robust graphics program--whether doing it in the cloud, or from a desktop version. Gravit seems to only work with versions 43 or newer (according to the error I got from some sketch f

Answer (score 6):

Illustrator doesn't open Sketch files. You'll need to open it in Sketch and export it to a vector format that Illustrator supports; namely PDF, EPS or SVG.

Which format you use depends on your artwork...

> Note: Some effects you can perform in Sketch are not supported by all vector file formats, including transparent gradients in PDFs, and inner and outer borders in SVGs.

https://www.sketchapp.com/learn/documentation/exporting/file-formats/

...If you don't have access to Sketch (or can't get whoever gave you the file to give it to you in a useable format; which would be the best option) you could try...

https://www.figma.com/ – which [has a free option](https://www.figma.com/pricing) and [imports Sketch files](https://help.figma.com/#_import).

You could also try something like https://convertio.co/sk-ai/ which claims to convert Sketch files (I don't have Sketch installed to try, but it works OK with other formats).

Comment: https://convertio.co/sk-ai/ did't work for sketch. But work for another things.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of apps that let you open a sketch file on windows and export assets:

- [Lunacy](https://icons8.com/lunacy) lets you open, do simple edits and export to .svg, which you can open in illustrator.
- [Gravit Designer](https://designer.io/) can open recent versions of sketch and export svg or pdf

Answer (score 0):

Exporting from Sketch as SVG using the Export controls in the Inspector (right side panel) worked well for me. Illustrator opened the exported file with the named layers and groups intact, exactly as they were set up in Sketch, and the file behaved as if I had created it in Illustrator. I was using Sketch 52.5 and Illustrator 23.0.1.